# Find, with proof, all the integers $a$ that satisfy the equation $\gcd\left(a,\:10\right)\:=\:a.$

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I have an idea of what to do.
I know that for $\gcd\left(a,\:10\right)\:=\:a$ to hold true, $a\le 10$ and $10$ also has to be a multiple of $a$.

Therefore, I think the only possible integers are $\pm 1,\:\pm 2,\pm 5,\:\pm 10$ but I'm not quite sure on how to prove this statement.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: "and $a$ also has to be a multiple of $10$" should be "and $a$ should be a divisor of $10$".

Comment: What about $\pm 2$?  It's just a question of listing the divisors of $10$.

Comment: According to the definition I'm used to, $\gcd(-5,10)=5$, not $-5$.

Comment: Depends on how you define $\gcd,$ I suppose, but usually $\gcd$ is defined to be positive (or non-negative, if you define $\gcd(0,0)=0.$)

Comment: @lulu forgot about 2, I edited the post.

Comment: @GregMartin I included the negatives because the question asked for integers. I assumed that if it was only naturals then the questions would've been something like 'find all the naturals....'

Comment: @Yaya123, by most conventions, the gcd is necessarily positive, since it's usually defined as the *greatest* integer that divides both arguments, hence greater than or equal to $1$ (which always divides both arguments). That would rule out negative values of $a$.

Comment: $\gcd(0,0)$ should definitely not equal $0$ (every positive integer is a common divisor of $0$ and $0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give this question slightly more mathematical content:

**Proposition.** For all $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b) = a$ if and only if $a \mid b$.

*Proof.* If $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b) = a$ then in particular $a \mid b$. On the other hand if $a \mid b$ then $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b) \geq a$, but $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b)$ cannot exceed $a$ so we have equality.

(So the answers are the positive factors of $b = 10$.)